# Python support for AES-NI

Tags: python, aes, aes-ni

Is there a way to make use of AES-NI in Python? I do want to make HMAC faster by making use of my hardware support for AES-NI.
Thanks.

Comment: You should react on answers Hamza, and please read the FAQ, especially regarding the use of tags. E.g. this question should definitely be tagged [[tag:python]] and [[tag:cryptography]]

Answer (score 2):

HMAC is using a secure cryptographic hash, not a symmetric cipher. You can make a "normal" MAC such as AES-CMAC perform better, but not a HMAC.

Comment: There is still no answer to the question, which could come handy for others finding this tread.

Comment: @ArekBulski Negative answers are also answers. You cannot make HMAC faster through use of AES-NI, not unless you can use a hash that is sped up using it. Note that on later Intel processors SHA-2 operations are also sped up and there is AES-CMAC. So I don't see the point of using a non-standard hash.