# AES-NI intrinsics in Cython?

Tags: python, aes, cython, simd, cythonize

Is there a way to use AES-NI instructions within Cython code?

Closest I could find is how someone accessed SIMD instructions: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cython-users/nTnyI7A6sMc/a6_GnOOsLuQJ

AES-NI in Python thread was not answered:
[Python support for AES-NI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007542/python-support-for-aes-ni)

Comment: Something like [pycrypto AESNI.c](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/master/src/AESNI.c) ?

Comment: @J.J.Hakala Then provide sample code and put it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just define the intrinsics as if they're normal C functions in Cython. Something like

```
cdef extern from "emmintrin.h": # I'm going off the microsoft documentation for where the headers are
    # define the datatype as an opaque type
    ctypedef struct __m128i:
        pass

    __m128i _mm_set_epi32 (int i3, int i2, int i1, int i0)

cdef extern from "wmmintrin.h":
    __m128i _mm_aesdec_si128(__m128i v,__m128i rkey)

# then in some Cython function
def f():
   cdef __m128i v = _mm_set_epi32(1,2,3,4)
   cdef __m128i key = _mm_set_epi32(5,6,7,8)
   cdef __m128i result = _mm_aesdec_si128(v,key)
```

---

The question "how do I apply this over a `bytes` array"? First, you get a `char*` of the bytes array. Then just iterate over it with `range` (being careful not to run off the end).

```
# assuming you already have an __m128i key
cdef __m128i v
cdef char* array = python_bytes_array # auto conversion
cdef int i, j

# you NEED to ensure that the byte array has a length divisible by
# 16, otherwise you'll probably get a segmentation fault.
for i in range(0,len(python_bytes_array),16):
    # go over in chunks of 16
    v = _mm_set_epi8(array[i+15],array[i+14],array[i+13],
            # etc... fill in the rest 
            array[i+1], array[i])

    cdef __m128 result = _mm_aesdec_si128(v,key)

    # write back to the same place?
    for j in range(16):
        array[i+j] = _mm_extract_epi8(result,j)
```

Comment: Can that produce a loop that decodes an array without a bunch of function-call overhead inside each iteration?  If not, you probably need to write encode/decode C functions.

Comment: Yes - I believe so. Cython can generate C code that can iterate over arrays and call C functions with speeds pretty comparable to C. (And when the C compiler sees those "function calls" it should translate them directly to a single processor instruction (hopefully!) rather than actually doing a function call).

Comment: Looks fantastic. Now how do I apply this over a bytes (Python 3) object?

Comment: Doing `_mm_extract_epi8` 16 times looks horrible.  If you're lucky, that might compile to a single unaligned store, but if not it'll be some nasty bloated code.

Comment: @PeterCordes I agree! I'm certain it could be done much quicker. I really just wanted to answer the original question of "how do I use AES-NI instructions in Cython?" I'm happy to admit that using the instructions efficiently (or even knowing what they actually do...) is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: @DavidW: ok, fair enough.  I don't know anything about Cython, or else I'd be able to answer this. >.<  I also haven't written AES encode/decode functions, but I think it's not *quite* as simple as a single instruction.  There's at least a key setup instruction.  How to string together intrinsics to implement AES is something you can google easily, though.  To load or store 16 bytes at a time, use `_mm_loadu_si128` or `_mm_storeu_si128` on a 16-byte object.  The trick is probably communicating to Cython the fact that you're accessing that many bytes.

Comment: `ctypedef struct __m128i x:` gives me a `Syntax error in struct or union definition`

Comment: @ThomasAhle I think delete the `x`. I've no idea why I put it there originally but I suspect it was a mistake. It compiles (and makes sense) for me without the `x`